# Update in HighCharts in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, yii

After this is the HTML code for a button HideAll, but it can't seem to update the graph, here the title name.

Clicking Hide All button has no effect. What changes should I make so that it affects monitoringChart?

I have removed most of the code from the Stockchart as its probably not relevant to this problem.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(__CLASS__."#JSONGraph",
"chart.destroy(); // Destroy the placeholder chart
$('#graphContainer').hide().html('<br /><br /><br /><h2 class=\"text-center\">Loading Data<br /><small>Just a moment...</small></h2>').fadeIn('slow');
var JSONDataXHR = $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '".$this->createUrl('jsonData')."?GasRecoveryMonitoring[datetime][]='+(Date.now()-1000*60*60*24*365*4)+'&GasRecoveryMonitoring[datetime][]='+Date.now()
});


JSONDataXHR.success(function(data) {        
    var monitoringChart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    title: {
        text: 'Recovery Rate %'
    },

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'graphContainer',
        height: 500,
        zoomType: 'x'
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },


    series: data


});

    $('#HideAll').click(function(){
        monitoringChart.update({
            title: {
                text: 'Inverted'
            }
        });
    });

});

JSONDataXHR.fail(function() {
    alert( 'FAILED' );
});




", CClientScript::POS_LOAD);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR, the success function is depracated as of jQuery 3.0. Use `done` instead.

Comment: Thank you but that doesnt seem to be the cause of the bug

Comment: If I replace monitoringChart.update({
            title: {
                text: 'Inverted'
            }
        });       with something like alert() then it seems to work fine..

Comment: Everything you've given here seems right then. Do any javascript errors occur? Maybe you aren't importing the right code from Highchart.

Comment: What if you try `new Highcharts.Chart` instead of `new Highcharts.StockChart`?